# Amazon Linux: yumm install php73 > "No package php73 available"

Tags: amazon-ec2, php7, amazon-linux

On an Amazon EC2 Linux server, I've run:

```
sudo su -
yum -y update
yum install -y php73
```

I receive the error `No package php73 available`.

I've been able to install `httpd`, `php`, & `php-mysql` okay.

Here is my yum repo list:

```
[root@ip-172-31-1-175 httpd]# yum repolist all
Loaded plugins: extras_suggestions, langpacks, priorities, update-motd
amzn2-core                                                          | 2.4 kB  00:00:00     
amzn2extra-docker                                                   | 1.3 kB  00:00:00     
amzn2extra-php7.3                                                   | 1.8 kB  00:00:00     
(1/2): amzn2extra-php7.3/2/x86_64/updateinfo                        |   69 B  00:00:00     
(2/2): amzn2extra-php7.3/2/x86_64/primary_db                        | 256 kB  00:00:00     
repo id                              repo name                              status
amzn2-core/2/x86_64                  Amazon Linux 2 core repository         enabled: 18,631
amzn2-core-debuginfo/2/x86_64        Amazon Linux 2 core repository - debug disabled
amzn2-core-source/2                  Amazon Linux 2 core repository - sourc disabled
amzn2extra-docker/2/x86_64           Amazon Extras repo for docker          enabled:     19
amzn2extra-docker-debuginfo/2/x86_64 Amazon Extras debuginfo repo for docke disabled
amzn2extra-docker-source/2           Amazon Extras source repo for docker   disabled
amzn2extra-php7.3/2/x86_64           Amazon Extras repo for php7.3          enabled:    305
amzn2extra-php7.3-debuginfo/2/x86_64 Amazon Extras debuginfo repo for php7. disabled
amzn2extra-php7.3-source/2           Amazon Extras source repo for php7.3   disabled
repolist: 18,955
```

I've created `/etc/yum.repos.d/amzn2-updates.repo`, but when I run `yum install php73`, I receive the error:

> Loaded plugins: extras_suggestions, langpacks, priorities, update-motd
>   Could not retrieve mirrorlist
>   http://repo.ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com/2/updates/mirror.list error
>   was 14: HTTP Error 403 - Forbidden
>
> One of the configured repositories failed (Unknown),  and yum doesn't
>   have enough cached data to continue. At this point the only  safe
>   thing yum can do is fail. There are a few ways to work "fix" this:
>
> ```
>  1. Contact the upstream for the repository and get them to fix the problem.
>
>  2. Reconfigure the baseurl/etc. for the repository, to point to a working
>     upstream. This is most often useful if you are using a newer
>     distribution release than is supported by the repository (and the
>     packages for the previous distribution release still work).
>
>  3. Run the command with the repository temporarily disabled
>         yum --disablerepo=<repoid> ...
>
>  4. Disable the repository permanently, so yum won't use it by default. Yum
>     will then just ignore the repository until you permanently enable it
>     again or use --enablerepo for temporary usage:
>
>         yum-config-manager --disable <repoid>
>     or
>         subscription-manager repos --disable=<repoid>
>
>  5. Configure the failing repository to be skipped, if it is unavailable.
>     Note that yum will try to contact the repo. when it runs most commands,
>     so will have to try and fail each time (and thus. yum will be be much
>     slower). If it is a very temporary problem though, this is often a nice
>     compromise:
>
>         yum-config-manager --save --setopt=<repoid>.skip_if_unavailable=true
> ```
>
> Cannot find a valid baseurl for repo: amzn-updates/2

This is my `/etc/yum.repos.d/amzn2-updates.repo`:

```
[amzn-updates]
name=amzn-updates-Base
mirrorlist=http://repo.$awsregion.$awsdomain/$releasever/updates/mirror.list
mirrorlist_expire=300
metadata_expire=300
priority=10
failovermethod=priority
fastestmirror_enabled=0
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-amazon-ga
enabled=1
retries=3
timeout=5
report_instanceid=yes

[amzn-updates-debuginfo]
name=amzn-updates-debuginfo
mirrorlist=http://repo.$awsregion.$awsdomain/$releasever/updates/debuginfo/mirror.list
mirrorlist_expire=300
metadata_expire=300
priority=10
failovermethod=priority
fastestmirror_enabled=0
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-amazon-ga
enabled=0
retries=3
timeout=5
report_instanceid=yes

[amzn-updates-source]
name=amzn-updates-source
mirrorlist=http://repo.$awsregion.$awsdomain/$releasever/updates/SRPMS/mirror.list
mirrorlist_expire=300
metadata_expire=300
priority=10
failovermethod=priority
fastestmirror_enabled=0
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-amazon-ga
enabled=0
retries=3
timeout=5
report_instanceid=yes
```

Help appreciated.

Comment: Are you on Amazon Linux 1 or 2?

Comment: `Amazon Linux 2 AMI`, @Tim.

Comment: The repo I sent you is for Amazon Linux 1, so perhaps use caution with AL2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I run the install on Amazon Linux v1 here's what I see

```
sudo yum install php73
Loaded plugins: update-motd, upgrade-helper
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package php73.x86_64 0:7.3.14-1.23.amzn1 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: php73-common(x86-64) = 7.3.14-1.23.amzn1 for package: php73-7.3.14-1.23.amzn1.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: php73-cli(x86-64) = 7.3.14-1.23.amzn1 for package: php73-7.3.14-1.23.amzn1.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: php73-common for package: php73-7.3.14-1.23.amzn1.x86_64
--> Running transaction check
---> Package php73-cli.x86_64 0:7.3.14-1.23.amzn1 will be installed
---> Package php73-common.x86_64 0:7.3.14-1.23.amzn1 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: php73-xml(x86-64) = 7.3.14-1.23.amzn1 for package: php73-common-7.3.14-1.23.amzn1.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: php73-process(x86-64) = 7.3.14-1.23.amzn1 for package: php73-common-7.3.14-1.23.amzn1.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: php73-json(x86-64) for package: php73-common-7.3.14-1.23.amzn1.x86_64
--> Running transaction check
---> Package php73-json.x86_64 0:7.3.14-1.23.amzn1 will be installed
---> Package php73-process.x86_64 0:7.3.14-1.23.amzn1 will be installed
---> Package php73-xml.x86_64 0:7.3.14-1.23.amzn1 will be installed
--> Finished Dependency Resolution

Dependencies Resolved

=============================================================================================================
 Package                   Arch               Version                         Repository                Size
=============================================================================================================
Installing:
 php73                     x86_64             7.3.14-1.23.amzn1               amzn-updates             3.6 M
Installing for dependencies:
 php73-cli                 x86_64             7.3.14-1.23.amzn1               amzn-updates             5.1 M
 php73-common              x86_64             7.3.14-1.23.amzn1               amzn-updates             1.4 M
 php73-json                x86_64             7.3.14-1.23.amzn1               amzn-updates              82 k
 php73-process             x86_64             7.3.14-1.23.amzn1               amzn-updates              95 k
 php73-xml                 x86_64             7.3.14-1.23.amzn1               amzn-updates             322 k

Transaction Summary
=============================================================================================================
Install  1 Package (+5 Dependent packages)

Total download size: 11 M
Installed size: 36 M
Is this ok [y/d/N]: n
Exiting on user command
Your transaction was saved, rerun it with:
 yum load-transaction /tmp/yum_save_tx.2020-02-28.20-47.yUTifC.yumtx
```

Here's the yum repo's I have available

```
> yum repolist all
Loaded plugins: update-motd, upgrade-helper
repo id                                 repo name                                            status
amzn-main/latest                        amzn-main-Base                                       enabled: 5,933+1
amzn-main-debuginfo/latest              amzn-main-debuginfo                                  disabled
amzn-main-source/latest                 amzn-main-source                                     disabled
!amzn-nosrc/latest                      amzn-nosrc-Base                                      disabled
!amzn-preview/latest                    amzn-preview-Base                                    disabled
amzn-preview-debuginfo/latest           amzn-preview-debuginfo                               disabled
amzn-preview-source/latest              amzn-preview-source                                  disabled
amzn-updates/latest                     amzn-updates-Base                                    enabled: 3,774+2
amzn-updates-debuginfo/latest           amzn-updates-debuginfo                               disabled
amzn-updates-source/latest              amzn-updates-source                                  disabled
!copart-restic/x86_64                   Copr repo for restic owned by copart                 disabled
!devopsx-amazon/x86_64                  DevopsX packages for Amazon Linux - x86_64           disabled
!download.mono-project.com_repo_centos_ added from: http://download.mono-project.com/repo/ce disabled
!epel/x86_64                            Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux 6 - x86_64       disabled
epel-debuginfo/x86_64                   Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux 6 - x86_64 - Deb enabled:   2,958
epel-source/x86_64                      Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux 6 - x86_64 - Sou enabled:       0
epel-testing/x86_64                     Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux 6 - Testing - x8 disabled
epel-testing-debuginfo/x86_64           Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux 6 - Testing - x8 disabled
epel-testing-source/x86_64              Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux 6 - Testing - x8 disabled
repolist: 12,665
```

I wonder if you have the correct repo enabled. If this doesn't help please edit your question to show your repo list with "yum repolist all".

If you need the Amazon Updates repo, try adding this to the file /etc/yum.repos.d/amzn-updates.repo

```
[amzn-updates]
name=amzn-updates-Base
mirrorlist=http://repo.$awsregion.$awsdomain/$releasever/updates/mirror.list
mirrorlist_expire=300
metadata_expire=300
priority=10
failovermethod=priority
fastestmirror_enabled=0
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-amazon-ga
enabled=1
retries=3
timeout=5
report_instanceid=yes

[amzn-updates-debuginfo]
name=amzn-updates-debuginfo
mirrorlist=http://repo.$awsregion.$awsdomain/$releasever/updates/debuginfo/mirror.list
mirrorlist_expire=300
metadata_expire=300
priority=10
failovermethod=priority
fastestmirror_enabled=0
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-amazon-ga
enabled=0
retries=3
timeout=5
report_instanceid=yes

[amzn-updates-source]
name=amzn-updates-source
mirrorlist=http://repo.$awsregion.$awsdomain/$releasever/updates/SRPMS/mirror.list
mirrorlist_expire=300
metadata_expire=300
priority=10
failovermethod=priority
fastestmirror_enabled=0
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-amazon-ga
enabled=0
retries=3
timeout=5
report_instanceid=yes
```

Comment: Thanks Tim, I've added my repo list to the question.

Comment: I guess you either need to add the repo (I've copied the details above) or work out if you have a disabled repo that has the same software. You could also maybe find and add the PHP 7.3 repo maintained by whoever makes PHP.

Comment: Thanks again. I've created `amzn2-updates.repo` (to match the format of `amzn2-core.repo` & `amzn2-extras.repo`, but receive a different error now (added to my question).

Comment: hi Steve what is the result for php -v ?

Comment: Weird, @Aravinda, I see `PHP 7.3.14` returned.

Comment: I know it ! some times you don't have to specify php73. just  yum install php will do the same when the correct repo is there! its just the problem with naming in whatever the repo you tried.